# CDI - possible to get list of event observers?

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld

Is there a way to get a list of listeners for an event? I'm using weld with
glassfish 3.1.1. For example to find out which classes are observing TestEvent:

```
@Stateless
public class TestListener {
    public void listenToHello(@Observes TestEvent testEvent) {
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject the BeanManager and use its methods. Here is the method you could use - http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#resolveObserverMethods%28T,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation...%29.

Comment: Thanks, I've found an updated reference documnent that contains this information, but was missing from the version I'd been using.